# Use regex or wildcards with Cheerio?

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

Some websites append hash codes to their class names to make web scraping more difficult:

How could I identify a DOM element like this by the use of regex or wildcard for the class name?

```
<input value="" class="malt-input-Input-input-eb6b6d2b malt-input-Input-l-a04d5840">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `$('input[class*="malt-input"]')`

That's not the reason they do that btw, there's a different reason that we're not aware of.